# Parsing Advanced XML in Classic ASP

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I have the following multi-level XML tree that I am trying to parse.  I can easily get the first level, but cannot seem to figure out how to get the others after much searching.  Ultimately what we need is a full list of the data in each level iterating over each article as well as grabbing the article id. *Can someone assist me please?*

**XML:**

```
<search>
    <numresults>26707</numresults>
    <pagesize>20</pagesize>
    <articles>
        <article id="998">
            <title>my title 1</title>
            <url>www.google.com</url>
            <attributes>
                <performer>
                    <id>122</id>
                    <url>www.yahoo.com</url>
                    <name>Elvis</name>
                </performer>
            </attributes>
        </article>
        <article id="999">
            <title>my title 2</title>
            <url>www.microsoft.com</url>
            <attributes>
                <performer>
                    <id>123</id>
                    <url>www.aol.com</url>
                    <name>Aerosmith</name>
                </performer>
            </attributes>
        </article>
    </articles>
</search>
```

**Here is what I have that will work for the XML to get level one:**

```
Set objXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
Set objEvents = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

objXML.async = False
objXML.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", true
objXML.Load (sURL)

'CaSe sensitive
Set objEvents = objXML.getElementsByTagName("article")

NumEvents = objEvents.length 'zero based

Response.Write NumEvents

c = 0
Do Until c = NumEvents

    Set objEventDetails = objEvents.item(c)

    Title = Trim(objEventDetails.childNodes(0).text)

    Response.Write Title & "<br>"

    c = c + 1

Loop 'main XML feed loop

Set objEvents = Nothing
Set objXML = Nothing
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath instead of crawling next child.

Here's an example

```
Set xml = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
xml.Async = "False"

xml.Load("search.xml")

strReturn = ""

for each ndArticle in xml.selectNodes( "//article" )
    strReturn = strReturn + ndArticle.getAttribute( "id" ) + vbCrLf 
    for each ndChild in ndArticle.selectNodes(".//" )
        if ndChild.nodeName <> "#text"  then
            strLast = ndChild.nodeName
        else 
            strReturn = strReturn + strLast + "=" + ndChild.nodeTypedValue + "<br/>" + vbCrLf
        end if
    next
next

WScript.Echo strReturn
```

It creates

```
998
title=my title 1<br/>
url=www.google.com<br/>
id=122<br/>
url=www.yahoo.com<br/>
name=Elvis<br/>
999
title=my title 2<br/>
url=www.microsoft.com<br/>
id=123<br/>
url=www.aol.com<br/>
name=Aerosmith<br/>
```

Comment: When I run the above on the sample XML, i am not getting any results.  it's not getting in to the for loop.  no errors.

Comment: Hi Dennis, you'll have to debug through your code to figure out what's up.  Check that your XML is valid, I had to fix up the original sample you posted.  I'd start there.

Comment: I know - there was a typo I fixed in the xml example above. I tested the xml, it's valid.  This actually ran for you?  I am using the same exact xml I updated above and your *exact* code.  The odd thing is I tried similar code with select nodes and it did not work.  I am running latest version IIS

Comment: exact code:  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jrcbalv7pfzzzs3/AAAKEPQeXNf1aojbq1bThkbca?dl=0

Comment: i wrapped by for loop with "if xml.parseError = 0 then" and added this to see if there was an error.  response.write("Error Reason: " & xml.parseError.reason)  it came back with "Error Reason: The system cannot locate the object specified. "   I am thinking that's the issue... but why??

Comment: Yes, this ran for me.  You're on the right track, be sure that you run a strFileName = Server.MapPath( strFileName ) (or similar) to map to the location on your server.

Comment: I just saw that you're getting your XML from an external URL (so MapPath won't apply).  Make sure you can get the URL.  I recall that there are some settings for MSXML to be able to retrieve external URLs that you'll need to factor in as well, I ran into that several times

Comment: I am using a file (test.xml) that is in the same directory.  I also tried external and nothing.  Something is not right.  What's really odd is we are using the same EXACT code and mine will not run.

Comment: If it's a local file (on your server), then you'll have to use Server.MapPath to map to get a fully qualified file name.  Don't debug with print statements, use a debugger, so you can follow exactly what's going on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151956/discussion-between-william-walseth-and-dennis).

Comment: I will out the file up on one of my other sites and try an external call but I did try this with some other code and select modes was not kicking me into the loop.  Will text and be back in touch.  Thx for the help and dialog. Not a newbie on this stuff, something is whacky!! Thx again

Comment: Did this work without mappath since your example answer above did not have it in there.  Just local reference to file in same directory it seemed

Comment: I'm running in the CScript.exe engine, which uses the current folder.  In ASP, the current folder is where IIS runs from, so you need to use Server.MapPath to get the folder your website runs in.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this issue, this is how I solved it.  See this post:

[how to solve "The download of the specified resource has failed" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933511/how-to-solve-the-download-of-the-specified-resource-has-failed-error)

The last comment at the bottom worked for me.  There was an issue calling my URL from the same directory as the script (i know, totally forgot - rookie mistake), that then threw the other error of "The download of the specified resource has failed" leading me to this solution.

I think that there my be a security feature on my server blocking William's code from working above....

thanks for the help William!